# Removing outliers from data

Tags: data, filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to remove outliers from the following data:

```
Data={{0.105, 0.989213}, {0.106414, 0.988926}, {0.107828, 
  0.988636}, {0.109242, 0.988343}, {0.110657, 0.988049}, {0.112071, 
  0.987748}, {0.113485, 0.}, {0.114899, 1.}, {0.116313, 
  0.986826}, {0.117727, 0.986512}, {0.119141, 0.986196}, {0.120556, 
  0.995073}, {0.12197, 0.985551}, {0.123384, 0.0154883}, {0.124798, 
  0.984894}, {0.126212, 1.}, {0.127626, 0.984222}, {0.12904, 
  0.983887}, {0.130455, 0.983538}, {0.131869, 0.983197}, {0.133283, 
  0.}, {0.134697, 0.970927}, {0.136111, 0.98213}, {0.137525, 
  0.98177}, {0.138939, 1.}, {0.140354, 0.981041}, {0.141768, 
  0.980672}, {0.143182, 0.826229}, {0.144596, 0.979923}, {0.14601, 
  0.979546}, {0.147424, 0.979163}, {0.148838, 0.978778}, {0.150253, 
  0.978392}, {0.151667, 0.978}, {0.153081, 0.977605}, {0.154495, 
  0.977208}, {0.155909, 0.976807}, {0.157323, 0.976404}, {0.158737, 
  0.975999}, {0.160152, 0.55766}, {0.161566, 
  0.975177}, {0.16298, -0.000401533}, {0.164394, 0.974344}, {0.165808,
   1.00182}, {0.167222, 0.}, {0.168636, 0.973073}, {0.170051, 
  0.972646}, {0.171465, 0.972211}, {0.172879, 0.971787}, {0.174293, 
  0.971338}, {0.175707, 0.970898}, {0.177121, 0.970455}, {0.178535, 
  0.97001}, {0.179949, 0.96956}, {0.181364, -0.000767749}, {0.182778, 
  0.968655}, {0.184192, 0.968197}, {0.185606, 0.967738}, {0.18702, 
  0.967275}, {0.188434, 0.96681}, {0.189848, 0.966343}, {0.191263, 
  0.}, {0.192677, 0.965404}, {0.194091, 0.964925}, {0.195505, 
  0.964447}, {0.196919, 0.963967}, {0.198333, 0.963484}, {0.199747, 
  0.962999}, {0.201162, 1.}, {0.202576, 0.962022}, {0.20399, 
  0.961529}, {0.205404, 0.961034}, {0.206818, 0.960536}, {0.208232, 
  0.960036}, {0.209646, 0.959534}, {0.211061, 0.959029}, {0.212475, 
  0.958522}, {0.213889, 0.958013}, {0.215303, 1.}, {0.216717, 
  0.956987}, {0.218131, 0.956471}, {0.219545, 0.955953}, {0.22096, 
  0.955432}, {0.222374, 0.954909}, {0.223788, 0.954385}, {0.225202, 
  0.894605}, {0.226616, 0.953327}, {0.22803, 0.952796}, {0.229444, 
  0.952262}, {0.230859, 0.951726}, {0.232273, 0.951188}, {0.233687, 
  0.950648}, {0.235101, 0.950106}, {0.236515, 0.949561}, {0.237929, 
  0.949017}, {0.239343, 0.948467}, {0.240758, 0.947917}, {0.242172, 
  0.947364}, {0.243586, 0.946811}, {0.245, 0.946254}};
```

When I plot it, I do see a few outliers that I want to remove (as shown by the pink highlighter):

```
ListPlot[Data, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

And up close there are a few more that I would like to remove from the data:

```
ListPlot[Data, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Is there a way I can remove the shown outliers programmatically in Mathematica? Any tips/suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: I used Tukey's fences from Wikipedia; it worked great for me. The advantage with Tukey's is that you can easily vary its parameter k to be more or less strict about what is an outlier. Be ye sure you know why these outliers arose; there's gold in them thar hills.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could take a look at the built-in functions `FindAnomalies` and `DeleteAnomalies`.

We can use `LearnDistribution` on the `MovingMedian` of the data to get an idea of what data we would expect, and then use `DeleteAnomalies`.

```
ListPlot[DeleteAnomalies[
  LearnDistribution[MovingMedian[Data, 5], Method -> "Multinormal"], 
  Data], PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comparing with the original data:

```
newdata = 
 DeleteAnomalies[
  LearnDistribution[MovingMedian[Data, 5], Method -> "Multinormal"], 
  Data]

ListPlot[{Data, newdata}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

We can see that the points in red have been removed.

Comment: This is such a great answer, thanks so much, Carl!

Comment: No problem at all! I'm sure there's a more rigorous approach that you _should_ take, but they're really helpful functions since you could train `LearnDistribution` on any expected data and use it the same way. Plus this is such a nice example of "Mathematica Magic" that I feel is quite exemplary of the power of the language.

Comment: Yes, for my purpose, this worked great! It cleaned up the data for a much larger data set very nicely. I did not know about the function `LearnDistribution`. It was indeed magic. Thanks so much again!

Comment: With MMA V12.0 (Mac) your code fails with the error message  `DeleteAnomalies` : Options expected instead of  data.  Which version of MMA have you used?

Comment: 12.3 on Linux. According to the docs DeleteAnomalies was updated in 12.1, so maybe that's why.